# Help using compilation-mode or similar to use next-error to navigate bash debug output

Tags: debugging, bash, next-error

Using "set -x" in bash script, outputs each executed command to an ouput file. eg here is part of the bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This is called by (my) .xinitrc, xdm and _should_ be called by gdm,
# kdm, xdm, lxdm whatever. However, gdm needs xorg-x11-xinit-session
# on fedora else 'ln -s .xsession .xsessionrc). Alternatively, create
# a Xsession login for gdm with /usr/share/xsessions/xsession.desktop:
#

# [Desktop Entry]
# Encoding=UTF-8
# Name=XSession
# Comment=This session will run your ~/.xsession
# Exec=$HOME/.xsession
# Icon=
# Type=Application
#
# [Window Manager]
# SessionManaged=true

ERRFILE="$HOME/.xsession-errors$DISPLAY"
exec &> $ERRFILE

echo "==============================================================="
echo "Running .xsession ... $(date)"
export PS4='+$(basename ${BASH_SOURCE}):${LINENO}:${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'
set -x

[[ "$WM" ]] || {
    F=~/.config/desktop
    [[ -f $F ]] && source $F
}
[[ "$WM" ]] || WM=$(type $WM 2>/dev/null)

# fallbacks:

[[ "$WM" ]] || {
    WM=$(
        type startfluxbox 2>/dev/null ||
            type awesome 2> /dev/null ||
            type startkde 2> /dev/null ||
            type gnome-session 2> /dev/null
      )
    [[ "$WM" ]] && {
        set -- $WM
        WM=$1
    }
}

[[ "$WM" ]] || {
    F=/etc/sysconfig/desktop
    [[ -f $F ]] && source $F
    [[ -x "$PREFERRED" ]] && WM=$PREFERRED
    WM=$(type $WM 2>/dev/null)
}

# final unction:
[[ "$WM" ]] || WM=myterm

[ "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ] || {
    # eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
    echo ".xsession: sourcing /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*"
    source /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/* # should do the above
}

echo ".xsession: .Xmodmap etc:"
MODMAP="$HOME/.Xmodmap"
MODMAPVNC="$HOME/.Xmodmap.vnc"
XRESOURCES=$HOME/.Xresources
```

Here is some sample bash script output courtesy of "set -x".

```
===============================================================
Running .xsession ... Fr 4. Dez 02:29:45 CET 2020
+.xsession:28:[[ -n '' ]]
+.xsession:29:F=/home/rgr/.config/desktop
+.xsession:30:[[ -f /home/rgr/.config/desktop ]]
+.xsession:30:source /home/rgr/.config/desktop
++desktop:1:WM=i3
+.xsession:32:[[ -n i3 ]]
+.xsession:36:[[ -n i3 ]]
+.xsession:49:[[ -n i3 ]]
+.xsession:57:[[ -n i3 ]]
+.xsession:59:'[' unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-3769nUHNhO,guid=63a594a532295645f13a1a525fc99109 ']'
+.xsession:65:echo '.xsession: .Xmodmap etc:'
.xsession: .Xmodmap etc:
+.xsession:66:MODMAP=/home/rgr/.Xmodmap
+.xsession:67:MODMAPVNC=/home/rgr/.Xmodmap.vnc
+.xsession:68:XRESOURCES=/home/rgr/.Xresources
++.xsession:69:hostname -s
+.xsession:69:H=thinkpad-x270
+.xsession:70:XRESOURCES_HOST=/home/rgr/.Xresources.thinkpad-x270
+.xsession:71:XMODMAP_HOST=/home/rgr/.Xmodmap.thinkpad-x270
+.xsession:75:'[' -r /home/rgr/.Xresources ']'
+.xsession:75:xrdb -merge /home/rgr/.Xresources
+.xsession:76:'[' -r '' ']'
+.xsession:77:'[' '' -a -r /home/rgr/.Xmodmap.vnc ']'
+.xsession:78:'[' -z '' ']'
+.xsession:79:'[' -r /home/rgr/.Xresources.thinkpad-x270 ']'
+.xsession:80:'[' -r /home/rgr/.Xmodmap.thinkpad-x270 ']'
+.xsession:83:export BH_XSESSION=true
+.xsession:83:BH_XSESSION=true
+.xsession:86:xrandr -q
+.xsession:86:grep 'VGA1 connected'
+.xsession:92:ps -f -u bhepple
+.xsession:92:egrep 'gpg|ssh|gnome'
error: user name does not exist

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
+.xsession:94:echo '.xsession: print ssh & gpg settings (first):'
.xsession: print ssh & gpg settings (first):
+.xsession:95:env
+.xsession:95:egrep -i 'ssh|gpg'
+.xsession:95:sort
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
+.xsession:99:type gnome-keyring-daemon
gnome-keyring-daemon ist /bin/gnome-keyring-daemon
+.xsession:111:GPG=,gpg
+.xsession:112:type gpg-agent
gpg-agent ist /bin/gpg-agent
+.xsession:112:GPG=
+.xsession:114:GKD='gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets,ssh,pkcs11'
+.xsession:115:echo '.xsession: gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets,ssh,pkcs11'
.xsession: gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets,ssh,pkcs11
++.xsession:116:gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets,ssh,pkcs11
** Message: 02:29:46.108: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
+.xsession:116:eval SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
++.xsession:116:SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
+.xsession:118:export GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL GNOME_KEYRING_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK GPG_AGENT_INFO
++.xsession:121:ps -ef
++.xsession:121:awk '/[g]nome-keyring-daemon/ {print $2}'
++.xsession:121:head -n 1
```

I had a look at compilation mode and the corresponding regexps but I havent a clue how to set the correct regexp for that output buffer. Is that even the way?

All I want to do is be able to use next-error in that output file in order to set the current line in the source script.

Any suggestions?